# Check automatically when website updates content? (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I would like to automatically download a certain (podcast) file every time it is published on the podcasts' website. So this website updates its content irregularly, and adds a podcast to its html table once in a while. I know how to scrape websites and download files from them efficiently.

However, I would now like to write a tool which automatically checks the website once in a while and notices whether it has been changed or not. Any advice?

Comment: https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron - possibly with an ETAG compare if they send it